# Dealing with object's scope

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to write a game in Java with a `Player` class that has 2 subclasses: `HumanPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer`. I want to allow the user to choose which player to play against, and once chosen - to create the relevant object and play.

Since the object is created within an if statement, the compiler doesn't let me perform any operations outside the if scope. In other cases I would create the object within the class' scope but in this case I cant know in advance which object to create (human/computer)

Here is some code for illustration:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class HumanPlayer extends Player {
    public void play(){
        System.out.println("Human playing");
    }
}

public class ComputerPlayer extends Player {
    public void play(){
        System.out.println("Computer playing");
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class PlayerDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type 1 for human, 2 for computer");
        int selection = in.nextInt();
        if (selection==1){
            HumanPlayer player = new HumanPlayer();
        } else if (selection==2){
            ComputerPlayer player = new ComputerPlayer();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid answer");
        }
        Player.play(); //can't do that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harness the power of [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

```
Player player = null; // player should never be null as you would have thrown an exception, but for the sake of completeness
if (selection == 1){
    player = new HumanPlayer();
} else if (selection == 2){
    player = new ComputerPlayer();
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid answer");
}
player.play();
```

assuming the `Player` class has a `play()` method. I see it doesn't. Change your class `Player` to have an override-able `play()` method which you override in the sub types.